# Android custom ListViewAdapter used setOnClickListener not raise listView.setOnItemClickListener

Tags: android

I create custom ListViewAdapter

In adapter I use setOnClickListener

```java
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)

LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();

row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {})
```

In activity I create listview

```java
listView.setAdapter(new MyAdaper(this));

listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {})
```

But setOnItemClickListener not raised if use setOnClickListener

If comment setOnClickListener setOnItemClickListener raise

How to make that work, and setOnClickListener and setOnItemClickListener?

Comment: why do you want to use both ? I think both of them is equal for you ! mean that both of them do same thing

Answer (score 1):

If you use custom listAdapter you may set onclickListener to child Views in you're base View(in you're example - row); In call stack listView.setOnItemClickListener stands above row.setOnclickListener. Actually both give the same result because **row**(in this context) is a simple item in default ListView.

So solution in this case is :

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);        
    ((Button)row.findViewById(R.id.btn1)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {});
}
```

In above example i use xml file like a item of listView.layoutResourceId contains a Button(R.id.btn1). After that you can set click listeners to ListView and to Button.And it will be different listeners that will produce different \ the same result (it all depends on the implementation)

Answer (score 0):

I found next way (thanks Raghunandan about "you can't have both")

In adapter

```java
private android.view.View.OnClickListener onClickListener;
public void setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener l) {
    onClickListener = l;
}

private android.view.View.OnLongClickListener onLongClickListener;
public void setOnLongClickListener(android.view.View.OnLongClickListener l) {
    onLongClickListener = l;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        //My action
        if (onClickListener != null)
            onClickListener.onClick(view);
    })
}
row.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
        //My action
        if (onLongClickListener != null)
            return onLongClickListener.onLongClick(view);

            return true;
    }
});
```