# Android OnClickListener for ImageView inside auto-gen ListView from Adapter

Tags: android, listview, onclick, imageview

I have an list adapter that I use to make a list view

```
TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(ToDoList.this, R.layout.item_task, tasks);
setListAdapter(adapter);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

I'm trying to do an `onclick` for it, but it keeps crashing the app.

```
    ImageView iv_delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.task_delete_image);
    iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String tag_del = (String) v.getTag();
            dm.deleteItem(tag_del);
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent());
        }
    });
```

`Log`

```
05-02 17:46:19.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3766): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 17:46:19.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3766): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.geotasker/com.example.geotasker.ToDoList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 17:46:19.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-02 17:46:19.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-02 17:46:19.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-02 17:46:19.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-02 17:46:19.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 17:46:19.405: E/AndroidRuntime(3766):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.geotasker/com.example.geotasker.ToDoList}: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2211)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at com.example.geotasker.ToDoList.onCreate(ToDoList.java:55)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-02 17:56:16.281: E/AndroidRuntime(3861):     ... 11 more
```

Activity:

```
public class ToDoList extends ListActivity {

    private ActionBarActivity abarAct;
    DataManager dm;
    ArrayList<Task> tasks;
    Task task;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.task_list);

        abarAct = new ActionBarActivity();

        tasks = new ArrayList<Task>();
        task = new Task();
        dm = new DataManager(this);

        new GetGeoTasks().execute();

        ImageView iv_delete = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.task_delete_image);
        iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String tag_del = (String) v.getTag();
                dm.deleteItem(tag_del);
                finish();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.to_do_list, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_to_do_list, container, false);
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    private class GetGeoTasks extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

            tasks = dm.getAllTasks();
            Log.d("demo", "doInBackground ACCESSED");

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            TaskAdapter adapter = new TaskAdapter(ToDoList.this, R.layout.item_task, tasks);
            setListAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Log.d("demo", "onPostExecute ACCESSED");

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas at how I could access an `ImageView` inside of a layout that was created dynamically in a `ArrayAdapter`? Thanks for any help!

Comment: What's the exception causing the crash? Could you paste your logcat output?

Comment: Updated. It's like the activity runs, and it runs fine when I comment out the onclick.

Comment: What are you trying to do here: `startActivity(getIntent());`?

Comment: where's the rest of the log? It should show you which line is throwing the error. And where are you setting your OnClickListener? I don't see you using the convertView/inflated view to get your image, most likely causing your null pointer exception.

Comment: Refresh the activity. So I don't have to remove the view.

Comment: Would be interesting to see what `getIntent()` actually returns.

Comment: It is possible that `getIntent()` is null. I wouldn't recommend doing something like `startActivity(getIntent());` and to refresh the `Activity` it is in any case overkill.

Comment: your root cause is an NPE in following line: `ToDoList.onCreate(ToDoList.java:55)` ==> for the case you need help debugging the NPE: Could you please indicate what code is in this line?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing this: `abarAct = new ActionBarActivity();`? You should never try to instantiate an `Activity`, this will only cause problems.

Comment: Line 55: `iv_delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {`

Comment: And the activity originally extended the ActionBarActivity, my partner had done it. But some fragment things wouldn't work without it.

Comment: then `iv_delete == null`. About your partner's code with the ActionBarActivity field... you will have to change this ;-)

Comment: @Kenny post your task_list.xml

Comment: @XaverKapeller - please do not remove the OP's comment from their code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would assume that line 55 is `iv_delete.setOnClickListener(...)`. If `task_delete_image` is a View inside the ListView's item view, then you cannot use `findViewById()` here, as the ListView items haven't been created yet.

Your best alternative would be to modify your custom adapter (TaskAdapter), and set the `OnClickListener` in the `getView()` method for each item. See for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17770862/82788).

On a totally unrelated subject, finishing the activity and creating a new one just to refresh doesn't seem like a good idea.

On another totally unrelated subject ;) as the commenters to the question said, the ActionBarActivity member doesn't make a lot of sense. Activity classes should never be directly instantiated, the framework will do that with calls to startActivity().

Comment: he is using a custom adapter called `TaskAdapter` so it should be done in there and I think you meant `getView` instead of `getItemView`

Comment: Yes, you're correct on getView(). Sorry, got confused. :)

Comment: Do I add the code the the `OnClickListener` that get's the tag and deletes my stuff (my goal of the click)?

Comment: Yes, the Adapter's getView() should contain the setOnClickListener() and everything it involves. You might need to move some code around, for example to be able to access the DataManager from the adapter itself.

Comment: Yep, I added the adapter to my `Adapter` and it worked great! Thanks! Do you have any idea on how I can refresh the activity or remove the clicked element?

Comment: After updating the underlying data for the adapter, you should call notifyDataSetChanged(). That should redraw the ListView.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is ListActivity already has a built in onclicklistener you just put your code into it.  Untested answer.

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            String tag_del = (String) v.getTag();
            dm.deleteItem(tag_del);
            finish();
            startActivity(getIntent()); 
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't quite follow. Are you saying this code right here that you have goes into my adapter? Because I get errors when I put it into the activity.

Comment: onListItemClick is a method of listActivy http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html#onListItemClick%28android.widget.ListView,%20android.view.View,%20int,%20long%29